# Как исправить смещение изображения в TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте. Смещается изображение "удалить" (крестик), когда текст превышает длину. Как сделать, чтобы текст не смещал изображение справа, а к примеру просто переносился. И вот ещё вопрос, как прижать изображение к краю (справа).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TableLayout
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:id="@+id/datails_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Откуда"
                        android:id="@+id/item_title_point"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Адрес"
                        android:id="@+id/item_point"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </TableRow>



            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"

            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы абсолютно неправильно используете TableLayout.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы придумали какую то сложную и неправильную разметку, объяснять все ошибки и правила построения разметок займет очень большое количество времени, поэтому просто посмотрите, как надо и делайте выводы, пожалуйста.
Основное - не надо увлекаться контейнерами без необходимости - они очень ресурсоемкие, так же не надо указывать лишние параметры (и параметры, дублирующие параметры по умолчанию) для элементов разметки - это тоже напрасно расходует ресурсы устройства.

Контейнер `TableLayout` здесь избыточен - сейчас я для примера напишу, как верстать для таблицы,чтобы вы поняли, какие у вас ошибки, но правильно будет то, что написано ниже:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/datails_row"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <TableRow>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Откуда"
            android:id="@+id/item_title_point"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Адрес"
            android:id="@+id/item_point"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

  </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>
```

Параметр `weight` (вес) указывает, что элемент должен занимать всю доступную в родительском контейнере площадь по ширине, но не "претендовать" на площадь других элементов,выталкивая их за край экрана. Здесь мы указываем этот параметр именно для `LinearLayout`,так как он ближайший дочерний элемент, а не `TextView`, которые в него вложены. Так же указываем ширину контейнера `0dp`, так как дополнительное вычисление ширины не требуется, она будет рассчитана по параметру `weight`.
Элемент справа будет автоматически смещен к самому краю, так как для него указан параметр `wrap_content` - занимать только необходимое место, "вес" среднего элемента оставит ему только то, что необходимо "прибив" к самому краю. 
Для `TextView` мы указываем ширину `match_parent` - занимать всю площадь родительского контейнера, принципиальной разницы с `wrap_content` тут нет, но `match_parent` вычисляется существенно быстрее.
Для `ImageView` задано `layout_gravity="center_vertical"` - разместить в центре по вертикали, когда текст будет занимать более одной строчки, картинка будет выравнена по горизонтальной оси. 
Вы можете добавить необходимые паддинги для нужных вам отступов.

Так же я уже не стал исправлять выбранный вами `TableLayout` (возможно у вас есть причины использовать именно его), но **для родительского контейнера в данном случае во много более уместен гораздо менее "тяжелый" `LinearLayout`** (к тому же возможности `TableLayout` в данной разметке абсолютно не востребованы):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/datails_row"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Откуда"
            android:id="@+id/item_title_point"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Адрес"
            android:id="@+id/item_point"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. TableLayout у меня не несёт какой либо смысловой нагрузки. Первый раз верстаю под андроид, и многое по просту непонятно. Второй вариант, у которого парент LinearLayout, вот что получилось - https://pp.vk.me/c624820/v624820863/2fb3f/Uz8BvHSFcus.jpg
крестики всё равно не прижаты к правому краю

Comment: @ПавелДурa Установите контейнеру, в который вложена эта разметка (скорее всего `ListView`) ширину `match_parent`, а не `wrap_content`

Comment: огромное спасибо. А что посоветуете почитать про верстку, желательно на русском?

Comment: @ПавелДурa Если ответ верный, отметьте его галочкой. Каких то книг именно по верстке мне не встречалось. В любом годном учебнике по андроид на это уделяется достаточно внимания,но больше в основном сам как то доходишь - принцип KISS тут, как и везде, более чем уместен.